# how do I view the older version of the document without restoring?

Tags: versioning, version-history

If I add version to my documents and later on want to retrieve copy of an older version, how do I do that without restoring the older version? In my document library there is a file "test" that has two versions. How do I download the earlier version without restoring the older version?

Comment: Komal, that answer worked a treat! How nice to have things like this... so obvious in the GUI. Cheers!

Answer (score 28):

[image: Here's the screenshot]

Sorry for localized version - it's a history list. Note marked link and url in status bar - it's archived version. So you can simply download.

**Edit**

Although when you hover over the `Modified On` value there is a dropdown list, the Save option isn't there. To save, right click on the `Modifed On` value and choose <kbd>Save As</kbd>. This will save the document version itself

Comment: Hi, I just found this answer and I do not think I understand it. Where can you just download the old version? I can't seem to find that option in SP2007.

Comment: Hi! AFAIK it's the same in the 2007 version. But does version control enabled in your list? It's disabled by default and you need to enable it on the list settings page before you will be able to view the versions history. http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-server-help/enable-and-configure-versioning-for-a-list-or-library-HA010021494.aspx?CTT=3#BM3

Comment: My bad, I couldn't see the image at the moment I read the response so it didn't make sense to me. Now that I see it with the image attached I understand it. Thank you!

Comment: But when I open the drop-down, I get "version history", and select.  Next level down, I get a time-stamped list of the history of docs (so far, so good).  However, if I select the drop-down for one of the versions, it offers to "restore" where all I want to do is "read" -- I don't get a download option and I don't want to restore the old version in front of the current version.  Is there something wrong with site settings or is it user error?

Comment: You don't need to open the dropdown - just click on  the link I've highlighted in red.

Comment: I hate SharePoint!! For whatever reason the UI allows me to restore the previous version but not to actually view or download it.

Comment: Are you sure? look the the screenshot above - the "14.11.2011 12:57" string is the link to download the specific version. Have you tried to click on it?

Comment: +1 This works in SharePoint 2013 too

Answer (score 7):

Right click on version link [Ex: 14.11.2011 12:57] and open in new browser, pop up comes up with open/save option.Click on save button to save the specified version of the document.